# For which h is this set of vectors dependent?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

So I have 3 column vectors: $v_1=[1\quad 2\quad 1]$, $v_2=[2\quad  6\quad  3]$ and $v_3=[-1\quad  -4\quad  h]$. The question now is for what h these vectors are dependent. I got to:

[1  2  -1 0,   0  2  -2  0,  0  0 h+2 0]

But then I get stuck and don't know the answer (and neither the reasoning behind it). h+2=0, but what does -2 do for example?  Anyone who can help me? You would be of great help!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

- arrange the vectors as row in a matrix
- perform RREF and set the condition on $h$ to have linear dependence (i.e. #pivots $<3$)

Comment: I have to do it by hand, not in Matlab unfortunately. I tried arranging it in a nice matrix layout but seem to be unable to get that to work here for me :/

Comment: @Mick serch for related OP on MSE you can find many examples. Are you aware about RREF and its meaning? It is not a difficult calculation by hand

Comment: Yes that is with the echelon form right? I will look for the related OP, thanks :)

Comment: @Mick Yes let me know your results, I will check to it.

Comment: Okay, so I've come to h=-2 by doing RREF, does that seem right to you?

Comment: @Mick yes it is indeed equal to $v_1-v_2$